# OldGen usage goes up after Full GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Trying to debug a memory leak in a java program (running on linux 64bits), using VisualVM 1.3.

I noticed that after each click on the "Perform GC" button  in the VisualVM Monitor tab, the "used" value for the Old Gen memory pool goes up... which seems rather counter-intuitive...

That would make sense if "Perform GC" did trigger a GC for the young gen only (since some objects could then be migrated from young to old gen)... But not in the case of a full GC.

Has anyone has encountered this before ?  Thanks.

Eg.
1) OldGen Initial state:

PeakUsage
committed:1431 Mb
init:1431 Mb
max:1431 Mb
used:98Mb

Usage
committed:1431 Mb
init:1431 Mb
max:1431 Mb
used:98Mb

2) Perform GC

3) New state:

PeakUsage
committed:1431 Mb
init:1431 Mb
max:1431 Mb
used:105Mb

Usage
committed:1431 Mb
init:1431 Mb
max:1431 Mb
used:105Mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems quite possible that full GC could also cause migration of young gen objects to the old gen. Do you have some specific reason to think otherwise?

Comment: Put more clearly: Full GC won't, of course, delete anything in OldGen if there's no garbage in it.